# Indexing 250M URLs for infix search in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, full-text-search, postgresql-14

I have a very large Postgres table with about 250M rows, and a text column `url`. I want to be able to search against this in a performant way, eg. `SELECT url_id FROM urls WHERE url ILIKE '%somewebsite.com/directory/file%'`

What’s the right mind if index to use for this type of query?

I’ve had a lot of success with using HASH indexes for direct lookups, eg creating a hash index on `lower(url)` and then querying `WHERE lower(url) = 'something.com'`. This works well for direct matches but not for infix, obviously.

I also have used GIN trigram indexes, eg. `CREATE INDEX my_them ON urls USING GIN (title gin_tgrm_ops)`, which has very fast lookup for infix queries like `SELECT url_id FROM urls WHERE title ILIKE '%microsoft%'`. This is very performant for infix so I figured that this would work well for the URL lookups. However, I find that my queries are taking a long time after creating such an index on the `url` column.

Any suggestions on the right kind of index to use for this use case? Is it perhaps the case that trigram indexes won’t work as well on URL strings vs. natural language strings?

Also, for reference here is the query plan produced for my lookup query using a GIN trigram index. As you’ll see, Postgres does use the index but it still takes forever.

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on urls  (cost=1205.02..10574.12 rows=10209 width=16) (actual time=58120.833..58120.845 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (url ~~ '%somewebsite.com/directory/file%'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on url_trgm  (cost=0.00..1202.46 rows=10209 width=0) (actual time=58116.797..58116.798 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (url ~~ '%somewebsite.com/directory/file%'::text)
 Planning Time: 4.449 ms
 Execution Time: 58123.684 ms
(7 rows)
```

————

Update: here’s the query plan with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on urls (cost=1288.15..10564.78 rows=10136 width=16) (actual time=43096.969..43096.974 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (url ~~* '%somewebsite.com/directory/file%'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   Buffers: shared hit=82900 read=43039 written=2801
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on url_trgm  (cost=0.00..1285.62 rows=10136 width=0) (actual time=43094.481..43094.481 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (url ~~* '%somewebsite.com/directory/file%'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=82900 read=43038 written=2801
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning Time: 1.522 ms
 Execution Time: 43097.294 ms
(11 rows)
```

---

Here's a 3rd query plan, with track_io_timing set to `on`. I also increased my shared_buffers from 256MB -> 1GB.

```
explain ( analyze, buffers ) select url_id from urls where url ilike '%somewebsite.com/directory/file%';
                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on urls  (cost=718.56..10008.01 rows=10150 width=16) (actual time=733.058..733.061 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (url ~~* '%somewebsite.com/directory/file%'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   Buffers: shared hit=52441
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on urls_url_trgm  (cost=0.00..716.02 rows=10150 width=0) (actual time=733.026..733.027 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (url ~~* '%somewebsite.com/directory/file%'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=52440
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning Time: 0.487 ms
 Execution Time: 733.105 ms
(11 rows)
```

Comment: Is this always slow, or does it get faster with repeat execution?

Comment: Turn on track_io_timing, then repeat with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

Comment: @jjanes sure! Just added the new query plan. Also, it seems to always be this slow

Comment: What version pg_trgm is being used?  If you got to v14 through pg_upgrade from a much older server, it might be using a much older version of pg_trgm than the current one.  If that is the case, `alter extension pg_trgm update;` might give you a vast improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the new plan, but it didn't have track_io_timing turned on.  turning it on does require a superuser, so you might need to cajole or bribe someone into doing it for you.  I would just set it on system wide by default, as it is so useful.

Comment: I have pg_trgm 1.6, which I’m pretty sure is the latest version.

Comment: Yes, that is the latest.  My remaining theory then is that is just the overwhelming commonness of a few trigrams, probably 'com' and its partials.  How does it perform if you just replace '.com/' with '.___/' ?

Comment: @jjanes just added a 3rd query plan which has track_io_timing. The other variable I changed was to increase shared_buffers. I am increasingly convinced that infix search is just not going to work in a performant way. It's sub-1s, but that's not fast enough for my purposes. I've been spoiled by postgres' phenomenal hash index implementation...